# Appending WWW to the start of Url String

Tags: java

i have a `url` in string say `http://google.com` and i want to append `www` to it's start and convert it to `http://www.google.com`. kindly share if there is some built-in class in java to do that or some algorithm that does the same.

Comment: And what you have tried so far ?

Comment: I tried parsing the URL that went messy. :-(

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you please show us your code so that we can correct it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple, and reasonably stable approach would be to replace `http://` with `http://www.`. You can do this with `java.lang.String#replace`.

Be careful not to call this on a string that has already been converted: a crude enclosing `if` block would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use:

```
x = x.substring(0,x.indexOf(":")+3)+"www."+x.substring(x.indexOf(":")+3);
```

where `x` is the URL.

It can convert:

- `http://whatever.com` to `http://www.whatever.com`
- `https://whatever.com` to `https://www.whatever.com`

Comment: I tired this, this appends an extra WWW to the url

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `StringBuilder` like this:

```
  String url = "http://google.com";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(url);
    sb= url.startsWith("http://") ? sb.replace("http://".length(), "http://".length(), "www.") : sb.append("");

    url = sb.toString();
          System.out.println(url);
}
```

Out put:

```
  http://www.google.com
```